# Why adding a Jar in android 64 library not work, only in android 32 bit

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When I try to add a jar in android **64 bit library** of my project it's not work. The jar is only added in the **32 bit version** of my project. Note: my project work very well in both 64 bit and 32 bit version, just that i m a little worry to not see my jars under the 64 bit version of my project. Is it a normal behavior ?

[image]

[image]